# How would I write this generator function by calling iter explicitly to skip the first values that don't satisfy the predicate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

**So I am trying to write this generator function and this is how I am trying to write it but it is not working and i'm not too sure how to call 'iter' explicitly. Any help would be appreciated!**

Write a generator named skip_until that takes as arguments a predicate and any iterable; it skips
producing the initial values produced by the iterable for which the predicate returns False, and then
produces the first value for which the predicate evaluates to True and produces all others after that one
whether or not they satisfy the predicate. For example, iterating over:

```
skip_until(lambda x: len(x) > 1, ['x', 'y', 'abc', 'a', 'xyz'])
```

would skip producing 'x' and 'y' (because their lengths are not > 1) but
then produces the values 'abc', 'a', and then 'xyz' (because 'abc' is the first value whose length is > 1,
so it and all subsequent values are produced. Call iter explicitly.
'''

```
def skip_until(p,iterable)
    for i in range(iterable):
      if p(i) == True:
        for x in range(i,len(iterable)):
           print(x)
      else: 
        pass
```

How can i call iter explicitly to get the proper results?

Comment: `skip_until` is not a generator. It does not `yield` anything. It does not even `return` anything. Hint: get rid of `print`. Also, `range(iterable)` is illegal, and even if it were legal, you would apply the predicate to the index, not to the item.

Comment: def skip_until(p,iterable)
    for i in range(iterable):
      if p(i) == True:
        for x in range([i:iterable]):
           yield(x)
      else: 
        pass

Comment: would that work?? :o

Comment: Why do you ask if you can try?

Comment: `def skip_until(p, iterable):
 for i, j in enumerate(iterable):
  if p(j):
   return iterable[i:]`

Comment: how can we use iter explicitly there?^^

Comment: do you want to return the cursor where on meeting condition?

Answer (score 0):

First, no reason to re-invent the wheel.  Look at [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), and just invert your predicate.

Second, if you're going to deal with iterators, then you can't assume that they're sliceable, or that you can get their lengths.  Basically the only things you can do to get values are `for` loops, `next`, and `yield from`.

Also, and I don't want to sound condescending here, all you have to do to call [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) explicitly is `iter(iterable)`.  That returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) over your [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

```
def skip_until(p,iterable):
    try:
        it = iter(iterable)
        curr = next(it)
        while not p(curr):
          curr = next(it)
        yield curr
        yield from it
    except StopIteration:
        return 

print(list(skip_until(lambda x: len(x) > 1, ['x', 'y', 'abc', 'a', 'xyz'])))
# ['abc', 'a', 'xyz']
```

Comment: what does "yield from it" do? what is it

Comment: @generation_coding [It's syntax introduced in Python 3.3 for delegating to subgenerators](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator).  Here, it's basically the same as `for x in it: yield x`